# tcpview cannot kill connection/process

Tags: tcp

I have a program that sometime misses to close a tcp connection.

After the program has ended I can see that the port is taken. TCPViewer shows "non-existent" in the "Process" column.

If i try to "End process" or "Close connection" nothing happens.

If i reboot the server the port is released. But how can I tell Windows to release this port without a reboot?

SOLUTION: It was dw20.exe (Microsoft Error Reporting) that was holding it back.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "release the port"? It doesn't make sense with connections.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? Have you tried starting tcpviewer as administrator?

Comment: I'm running windows 2008 server as admin

Answer (score 1):

The operating system will automatically close all TCP connections when a process exits<sup>1</sup>.

What you are seeing is probably a connection in the TIME-WAIT state ("...represents waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the remote peer received the acknowledgment of its connection termination request").

This should *not* be a problem for clients, as a host can establish multiple TCP connections to the same remote host:port.

For a server, SO_REUSEADDR can be used.

> #### [What exactly does SO_REUSEADDR do?](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml)
>
> This socket option tells the kernel that even if this port is busy (in
>     the TIME_WAIT state), go ahead and reuse it anyway.  If it is busy,
>     but with another state, you will still get an address already in use
>     error.  It is useful if your server has been shut down, and then
>     restarted right away while sockets are still active on its port.  You
>     should be aware that if any unexpected data comes in, it may confuse
>     your server, but while this is possible, it is not likely.
>
> It has been pointed out that "A socket is a 5 tuple (proto, local
>     addr, local port, remote addr, remote port).  SO_REUSEADDR just says
>     that you can reuse local addresses.  The 5 tuple still must be
>     unique!" by Michael Hunter (mphunter@qnx.com).  This is true, and this
>     is why it is very unlikely that unexpected data will ever be seen by
>     your server.  The danger is that such a 5 tuple is still floating
>     around on the net, and while it is bouncing around, a new connection
>     from the same client, on the same system, happens to get the same
>     remote port.  This is explained by Richard Stevens in ``2.7 Please
>     explain the TIME_WAIT state.''.

See also this StackOverflow answer: [Using SO_REUSEADDR - What happens to previously open socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775638/using-so-reuseaddr-what-happens-to-previously-open-socket)

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, when all handles to that connection are destroyed. Multiple processes may own a file handle.

Comment: i forgot to say that it is a host. Does that change anything?

Comment: i get a AddressAlreadyInUseException when starting the program again

Comment: @Stig: What do you mean by "host"? A program that listens for connections?

Comment: @Stig: Answer updated to explain server sockets.

Comment: Yes it is a program that listens for connections! A service waiting for clients to retrieve data.

Comment: @Stig: That would be a "server" then.